# Is there a tool or add-in to track debugger usage in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

Just curious how much time my team spends running the debugger individually and collectively (as opposed to effective unit testing practices).  Is there tool that can track this metric?

Comment: I agree that it sounds like a great idea, but I'd caution that without knowing how much time an individual spends designing, writing, etc, and which (whose) code they're working on, it won't mean much. Also, I spend a lot of time debugging code others have written - it doesn't imply (for example) that I blindly code and debug rather than designing and trying to do my thinking up front.

Comment: I agree completely that this is just one aspect of a larger picture. I'm really just curious to have another metric for measuring and promoting productive time, and to help 'sell' automated testing practices, nothing punitive.  That said, I also spend time working with other's code and I spend time thinking about how to write tests against legacy code before making significant changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific that I know of for this, though it sounds like a great idea.  You could try asking the developers of [Visual Time Spent](http://www.svprogramming.net/visual-time-spent/index.html) and see if they can add a feature for you.